# Can we create multiple database in firebase for multiple reasons? This is for android platform and language is java

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

I already created a database on Firebase for user authentication. Now I need to make another firebase Realtime database to store users working days. My problem is can we create two databases in a single project?

Answer (score 1):

> My problem is can we create two databases in a single project?

Yes, you can create [multiple Realtime Database instances](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/sharding#create_multiple_instances) in the same project.

Comment: Hey. Can I help you with other information?